# ! Undefined control sequence

Tags: r-markdown

I am trying to print out cumulative probability function using R markdown in R Studio. Here is my code

```
$$
\left\{\begin{matrix} 
0 & if & y \lt 0 \\ 
\frac{1}{8} & if & 0 \leq y \lt 2 \\
\frac{4}{8} & if & 2 \leq y \lt 4 \\ 
\frac{7}{8} & if & 4 \leq y \lt 30 \\
1 & if & y \geq 30 
\end{matrix} \right\}
$$
```

but i am getting below error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.175 \left\{\begin{matrix} 0 & if & y \lt
                                           0 \\ \frac{1}{8} & if & 0 \leq y ...
```

Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to create a PDF document using LaTeX. In that case, there is no `\lt` comand in LaTeX. One just uses `<`. Full working code:

```
---
output: pdf_document
---

$$
\left\{\begin{matrix} 
0 & if & y < 0 \\ 
\frac{1}{8} & if & 0 \leq y < 2 \\
\frac{4}{8} & if & 2 \leq y < 4 \\ 
\frac{7}{8} & if & 4 \leq y < 30 \\
1 & if & y \geq 30 
\end{matrix} \right\}
$$
```

Comment: Thanks! It sure did work. Really appreciate it.Is there any quick reference of comparative command in LaTeX?

Comment: @Skat THese answers might help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner. If my answer was helpful, please consider accepting/up-voting it, c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.